# MySQL Error: This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, laravel

I am getting the following error when I use `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` to the start and end of my MySQL queries.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2030 This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet

SQL: START TRANSACTION

Bindings: array (
)
```

In Larvel, I did:

```
DB::query('START TRANSACTION');
```

I am using the PHP framework Laravel, which uses PDO to access MySQL. What should I do?

Comment: Need version numbers for PHP and MySQL

Comment: I had an old version of mysql running, thanks! Upgrading..

Comment: Please mark question as solved and edit your post with the solution!

Comment: @mblaettermann You don't mark a post as solved. You choose the best answer. In this case there is no provided answer that solves the solution so the OP should make one - not edit the post

Comment: The post below that I chose solved the problem, along with an upgrade of MySQL. Why the downvote? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel already has a support for transaction query.

```
DB::transaction(function ()
{
    // query goes here.
    DB::table('foo')->insert(array('foo' => 'bar'));
});
```

Comment: Please also answer the question.